# Is it true that hiden jutsu can be taught?

Tags: naruto

I was browsing through naruto wiki, and came across this [page](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Hiden)

It is stated that ,

> They are not to be confused with kekkei genkai, as technically, hiden techniques can be taught to anyone.

By "they", it means Hiden Jutsu. Is it true that they can be taught to others? Is there any evidence of this happening?

I remember in the Boruto movie that the Shadow Jutsu is used through that advanced gadget. But is it possible for a person who does not have any clan relationship to learn a Hiden Jutsu?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd go with **Yes.**

Hiden Jutsu are hidden clan techniques that are passed only within a clan. The nature and need for secrecy arises only because they can be "stolen". Ergo someone outside the clan can learn these techniques. I would also guess that someone outside the clan can also be adopted and taught those techniques. If they meet the criteria they can also figure out by themselves. Lets take some examples.

1. **Hyuuga Clan:** Byakugan may be a kekkei Genkai, i.e. Someone only from Hyuga Clan can manifest these eyes. But Neji for example, just because of his natural talent figured out *Hiden* techniques such as 32/64 Palms, Rotation etc. Later his uncle taught them to him popularly. Now Ao may possess the Byakugan but unless taught he can't use any Gentle Fist techniques.
2. **Uchiha Clan**: Kakashi, Danzo etc. have shown to be able to use the clan's Hiden techniques once acquiring the Sharingan. These include Genjutsus, specialized techniques such as Izanami, Kamui etc.
3. **Ina-Shika-Cho**: We see other users using the "Reading of mind" on the ninja Jiraiya sent. But when Pain uses it on Shizune, Ino remarked on it as "Dad's Technique". I would think that such techniques are specialized by the Yamanaka clan which may or may not be passed outside. Nara Clan's shadow technique was not used outside the clan. Akimichi Clan probably requires the genetic body build to use the Body Expansion techniques.
4. **Team 8** - Both Aburame and Inuzuka clan raise the children in such a way that they can use their Hiden techniques. The kids in Aburame clan bond with insects, while Inuzuka clan raise a puppy and grow together with them.

Thus Hiden techniques are secret since each individual are brought up/born in a manner that they can only learn their clan techniques. 
If Iron Fist Style can be taught, why not the Gentle Fist with someone with precise Chakra Control? Because they don't have the Byakugan to precisely dodge and target the areas while fighting.

Comment: well written answer. But for the Hyuga part of your explanation , it seems that a person requires the Byakugan eyes. Shadow techniques are enabled by Yin release and since everyone has a shadow, it doesnt mean they can do the Nara clan's Jutsus and similarly to Akimichi clan's Body Expantion Jutsu, which Yang release. I'll see if anyone gives a better explanation or else i'll assign this answer as correct answer. Thanks for your effect by the way. Cheers

Comment: The Uchiha don't have Hiden techniques, all of their techniques are Kekkei Genkai. Genjutsu: Sharingan, Kamui (an ability specific to the Mangekyo Sharingan), Izanami, Izanagi, and other Sharingan-specific jutsu are usable only by someone with a Sharingan. For a technique to be true Hiden, it must be **usable** by anyone, without anything more than training.

Comment: Notice most Hidden Jutsu are actually just Yin and/or Yang based, because everyone has those. Kekkei Genkai on the other hand are always either the ability to combine 2 elements, or a special organ. For chakra fusions, that is permanent, but the special organs can sometimes be transplanted, especially the eyes, to grant other users similar powers, though frequently at a greater cost. That however is not teachable.

Comment: @RFKomos Does that mean anyone with Sharingan can use Izanagi/Izanami other Sharingan techniques. Sharingan allows them to predict their opponents moves and cast basic genjutsus. Other techniques need to be taught or discovered.

Comment: @Ryan Agreed. But I am not talking about Kekkei Genkai ONLY. I am saying some jutsu's exist which can only be taught if the user has that specific organ. Instead of Gentle Fist, take Kakashi's Chidori. He created as a youngster, but it only became complete once he got the sharingan. Sasuke took it further. If an Uchiha had discovered Chidori and then passed it along his generation it might have been a Hiden Jutsu.

Comment: Is there any instance of Yin-Yang release type Hiden Jutsu being performed by people outside their clan?

Comment: @Arcane Yes, we saw this with Danzo using Izanagi. Chidori and Raikiri are both neither kekkei genkai nor hiden. They're techniques with drawbacks that become more powerful paired with a Sharingan. Theoretically, anyone can learn Gentle Fist style. But it would be pretty useless because you'd be blindly hoping you're striking chakra nodes, making it horribly ineffective. The only people it's **effective** for are Byakugan users, which is why only Hyuuga use it. Because only Hyuuga use it, only Hyuuga know it, making it Hiden.

Comment: @RFKomos Sort of my point. Chidori is ineffective without the sharingan and it could've turned to Hiden in a similar manner as that of Gentle Fist. For Example. Ao doesn't use gentle Fist even with his Byakugan

Comment: @Arcane It's not "ineffective" without the Sharingan. It's just that the Sharingan takes away the weakness of the Chidori/Raikiri. Naruto's Rasengan uses the exact same principle (punch someone with a ball of chakra) and it's very effective, as an example. Any jutsu "could" have gone Hiden, that's a pretty irrelevant point.

Comment: @Arcane The weakness of Raikiri/Lightning Blade that the Sharingan fixed was its raw cost to things like perception, mobility, and awarness. Kakshi almost died without the sharingan simply because he could not counter an attack while using his chidori he normally would have dodged. Minato saved him that time, but once he got his sharingan, he could follow and predict everyones movements, so not getting hit was easy again while using it.

Comment: I was asking about instances of Nara and Akimichi clan's Hiden Jutsu being used outside their clan. Is there any event of occurring like that?

Answer (score 0):

Hidden ninjutsu are justsu that reserved for a single clan or a single country. Those are secret justsu teaches by generation to generation. That is why it call hidden ninjutsu. It can be taught to anyone.