# Is there an incidence of a Hiden (Meaning Secret) Jutsu being used by someone OUTSIDE the clan?

Tags: naruto

Hiden Jutsu: http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Hiden

I answered this question : [Is it true that hiden jutsu can be taught?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/34554/is-it-true-that-hiden-jutsu-can-be-taught/34556)

I've researched quite a bit and tried to build an  understanding on these Jutsu. The OP asked for example instances where the jutsu is used by someone outside the clan sine they can be learned by anyone. I however could'n't find any such instance.

Can anyone else remember/find such an instance in Naruto (preferably Canon).
 **Boruto movie doesn't count cos the Scroll Stores the original jutsu casted by someone from the clan.**

Comment: Primary suspect -> Orochimaru

Answer (score 1):

Neji learned the Eight Trigrams Sixty Four Palms and Eight Trigrams Heavenly Rotation techniques through his own genius and skill - these techniques were not taught to branch members thus he would never have been taught them.

Ref: http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Eight_Trigrams_Sixty-Four_Palms

Edit: though not in the spirit of the question, technically Hashirama's Deep Forest Creation technique was his Hiden jutsu, but after his death was used by Madara after gaining Hashirama cells without any training.

Ref:http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Wood_Release_Secret_Technique:_Nativity_of_a_World_of_Trees

Also, in the Boruto movie Momoshiki can absorb and then use Hiden techniques

Comment: the question is outside the clan. even if they did'nt teach to branch members, he is still a Hyuga. We need someone outside the clan.

Comment: @Bej Hiden techniques were used to make interesting characters, making their techniques easily reproducible would have taken away something from their character. Also, this was the only true to the spirit of the question answer that I could find.  I'll edit it with what could technically be an answer

Comment: I'd shared the example of Neji figuring out the Advanced Gentle Fist techniques without training. Hashirama's techniques May've been copied with the Sharingan. I can't find a source citing Hiden techniques can't be copied... But kakashi not using them would counter  it

Comment: Using Neji is a bad example. The Hyuga hiden ninjutsu relies on a Kekkei Genkai, Byakugan. You need hiden ninjutsu that doesn't rely on Kekkei Genkai.

Comment: Neji is a great example. The fact that Gentle Fist utilizes the Byakugan is irrelevant. Neji learned a hidden technique he was not supposed to learn. The branch members were never meant to learn Heavenly Rotation or 8 Trigrams 64 Palms, they were supposed to be main branch Hiden techniques. But neji learned them through his own observations and genius.

Comment: Hasirama's Deep Forest is a Kekkei Genkai as much as if not more so than it is a Hidden jutsu. It is Wood Style after all. That being Said, I do not recall any actual examples besides Momoshiki who is almost an excception. To learn the jutsu, you would most likely need one who already knows it to teach it to you, something nearly impossible to do without mind control which we all know is pretty much nonexistant or extensive mind reading which is very inconvenient at best. Neji is probably the best example thanks to that.